# How to create REST API backend using parse.com in Java?

Tags: java, api, rest, parse-platform

I'm sort of new to http://www.parse.com . And I want to develop backend in Java using REST API. It seems parse.com does not provides direct Java library for REST API development. But I found some third party libraries(un-official) like for Java:
JAVA

[Almonds](https://bitbucket.org/jskrepnek/almonds) — A Java REST API that mimics the Android API.

[mobile-parse-api](https://code.google.com/p/mobile-parse-api/) — This library implements the REST API of parse.com in java with open interfaces for libgdx and playN.

[Parse4J](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j) — Library for the REST API.

[ParseFacade](https://bitbucket.org/sheng/parsefacade/wiki/Home) — Parse Android SDK alternative.

But I am not understainding how to get start with these libraries in order to create backend API in Java

Comment: Why don't you use a REST-Client-Library of your choice for Java? The big advantage of providing a REST-API is, that there are REST-client libraries for all programming languages. So you can use one of your liking, also depending on the specific "kind" of Java you are using (Android, JEE, ...)

Comment: But then how do I make use of parse ?

Comment: Well, that is what the Parse documentation is for ... But just having taken a quick look at Parse4J, why don't you just use that? What is your problem with using that library? It seems to encapsulate some boilerplate code when working with the Parse REST API from within Java, so it simplifies the coding.

Comment: I do have Parse4j library code imported in my eclipse. The problem is how they have performed CRUD operation or How can I start using that library ?

Comment: Well, SO is not a site which replaces good documentation. Sorry, but ask the author or browse through the code.

Comment: @DaDaDom How can I expose my API ?

Comment: I'm actually unsure what you are asking for exactly. Have you gone through [parse.com API documentation](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/) and/or [parse4j github with short documentation](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j) yet? What exact problems have you faced while trying to use them. Any exceptions? Any logical walls you can't handle? Or is it just that you do not know how to create your own RESTful API in general? Here JAX-RS or SpringMVC might be worth a lookup

Answer (score 0):

@Mahendra 
I assume by now you have found your answer. In case you haven't then here is a thought process that might be of interest.

From the little reading I have done on Parse.com it is a sort of like an Object database in itself which provides ready REST style api for all data stored there. See this - https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide

In addition they provide libraries for all popular Front Ends (iOS, Android, JS). 
I think they are advocating a paradigm shift for programmers who are used to having a lot of processing on the Backend servers and exposing simpler rest API which provides a processed and targeted response to each http request.
Basically they are suggesting that the whole backend infrastructure (db, app server, server side logic etc) can be replaced by parse.com
If you are considering using Parse.com I assume you have read and understood above mentioned thought process and decided that it makes sense for your project.

I would advise you to consider using a using a common client side Java library that works with the Parse rest api and then use appropriate Client SDK (iOS, Java, JS etc) to work with your library and design the UI. Since you are asking about Java library, I assume your language of choice for storing processing logic is Java. 
What I suggest next may be bit of a long shot ... but worth a consideration. 
Write code non-ui code in Java and work with the Android API from Parse.com. Use a Java to Objective C. https://github.com/google/j2objc
This will also allow you to use Java code for your web browser (using GWT as a UI framework).

Then write UI code in the framework suited for the platform (obj c for ios, Java for Android, GWT + Java for web browsers) and use the java library to connect to Parse.com.

If you have already tried out such an approach would be good to write back opinions in a comment so the community may benefit.